# Where to find a comprehensive content on security proof systems in cryptography

Tags: provable-security

Proof systems (provable security) are seen in many research papers related to cryptography and security. Where would I be able to find a comprehensive resource covering the purpose and the fundamentals of proof systems, and its common approaches such as the random oracle model method?

Answer (score 1):

First, as a heads up "approaches to provable security" or "approaches to security proofs" (which it sounds like you are interested in) means something different than "proof systems" in cryptography. Proof systems are a specific construct that are studied within cryptography (similar to encryption or signatures), of which zero-knowledge proofs are the best known example. The fact that there is a naming collision here is unfortunate, but its best to just keep it in mind and sometimes uses more awkward phrasing to avoid the collision.

There are a number of slightly different competing notions of "proof systems". I don't know a resource that collects them all into one document, but two popular ones are:

1. Bellare and Rogaway's "Game-playing" model, which you can find exposition on [here](https://eprint.iacr.org/2004/331.pdf)
2. The "simulation" proof technique, which you can find exposition on [here](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/046.pdf)

As for the random oracle model, I believe [chapter 6](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-0-387-27712-7_6) from Katz's book *Digital Signatures* is probably a good pointer, although if you do not have institutional access it may not be freely available.

**EDIT**: Browsing eprint, I found [this](https://eprint.iacr.org/2021/088.pdf) chapter on hybrid arguments, which also may be interesting.